# How to exclude link hover in footer

Tags: css, mousehover

At first my theme was working great, all my links had hover animations, one day it changed and I couldn't find a way to change it back, I wrote to the developers but from all my questions this was the one they ignored.
I'm very new with coding so I searched and I did it, the code in my child theme now looks like this:

```
a:link {
color: #000000;
footer: none!important;
}


a:visited {
color: #000000;
footer: none!important;

}


a:hover {
color: #666666;
footer: none!important;
}


a:active {
color: #666666;
footer: none!important;
}
```

BUT my problem is that it keeps applying the hover to my footer (it has a different text color)

I tried with

```
footer: none!important;
```

and with

```
footer_wrapper: none!important;
```

But it's not working, what am I doing wrong?
I just want to exclude the child css link hovering from my footer, because my theme gives me the option to style the footer, my footer works fine, but not after the changes made to all the other links.

My website is: http://thenoirportrait.com

Comment: You're using selectors as property names. Make footer look like the `a {}` and put `display: none` or something inside the braces.

Comment: I did it, and now I don't have any text in the footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your code:

```
footer a {
  color: #FFF !important;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #888 !important;
}
```

Comment: It works! But now my footer has no hover animation. 
I just want to exclude the child css link hovering from my footer, because my theme gives me the option to style the footer, my footer works fine, but not after the changes made to all the other links.

Comment: ok, so take out `, footer a:hover` from the above and add `footer a:hover { color: **your hover colour** }`

Comment: Nope, nothing happens, the code stops working once I delete    , footer a:hover

Comment: send me a link to a website that has the effect you want

Comment: This is my website: http://thenoirportrait.com
I want to apply the hover effect that I added to my child theme to my body only not my footer, my footer already has a hover animation. That's all I want :(

Comment: did you add the effect to your child theme with css? or did you make the change in the theme settings?